# Determine if argument in pthread_create from main thread is NULL in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to figure out if the pointer passed to `pthread_create` is NULL and has already been freed. However, in the code below, `idx` still contains the memory address, i.e., `$1 = (int *) 0x601010`

Is there a way to determine if `idx` has been freed and is NULL?

```
#include <pthread.h>

void *foo(void *i) {
    int a = *((int *) i); 
    free(i);
    i = NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    int *idx = malloc(sizeof(*idx));
    pthread_create(&thread, 0, foo, (void *) idx);
    pthread_detach(thread);
    sleep(10);
    // if (idx == NULL) // contains (int *) 0x601010
    // puts("done");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `pthread_detach`, you could `pthread_join`. When the join returns, you can be sure that the memory is freed.

Comment: `idx` is a local variable, and you are passing its value. So there is no way that `foo` could modify its value even if it wanted to. You also never initialize the memory that `idx` points to, so `a = *(int*)(i)` in `foo` has unspecified behaviour.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, I'll look into `pthread_join`, however, I was curious if it was possible still using pthread_detach.

Comment: @rici make sense now. Can I pass `(void *) &idx);`?

Comment: In your thread function, `i` is a local variable.  You can modify or free the memory it points to, but it has no inherent connection to the expression that served as the corresponding argument.

Comment: If you want to detach the thread, then give the thread responsibility for freeing the allocated memory before it stops, instead of expecting `main()` to do it.

Comment: As everyone is pointing out, you should pass a pointer to a pointer to foo(void **i) for the reassignment to have an effect.

Comment: okay, I believe I understand now. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Remember than in C, all function call parameters are passed by value, so never, never, never a pointer that has been `free()`d will be null, but if you make it's value, just after free call.

When you do

```
void *p = malloc(100);
...
free(p);
```

and then check the value of `p`, it will be the same as before calling `free(3)`, because the only thing you can do to force it to `NULL` is to explicitly assign it that value.  Like this:

```
free(p); p = NULL;
```

Remember that the only way to fail in `free(3)` is to pass it a reference to a non allocated pointer, and this normally hangs the program (undefined behaviour)  So, if you want to ensure the pointer is not usable, just assign `NULL` to it.